# CryptoJS AES Code Equivalent to c# code

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

Below is a working c# Cryptography Code.

*Included namespace reference*

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
```

***C# code to encode json format user data***

```
// Encode the data into a JSON object     
JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json_data = s.Serialize(user_data);

string site_key = "84129";
string api_key = "0d2c15da-b36f-4a9c-8f44-93eb95811e2e-05e1fb36-54aa-44fc-888e-45d2669c3013";
byte[] bIV = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

//Using byte arrays now instead of strings
byte[] encrypted = null;
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json_data);

//Use the AesManaged object to do the encryption
using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
{
    aesAlg.IV = bIV;
    aesAlg.KeySize = 16 * 8;

    // Create the 16-byte salted hash     
    SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    byte[] saltedHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(api_key + site_key), 0, (api_key + site_key).Length);
    Array.Resize(ref saltedHash, 16);
    aesAlg.Key = saltedHash;

    // Encrypt using the AES Managed object  
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();
    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}

// the Base64-encoded encrypted data       
 string encodedData= Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted, Base64FormattingOptions.None)
              .TrimEnd("=".ToCharArray()) // Remove trailing equal (=) characters       
              .Replace("+", "-")   // Change any plus (+) characters to dashes (-)     
              .Replace("/", "_");  // Change any slashes (/) characters to underscores (_)
```

*Note : json_data string is like..*

*{"email":"chandresh@domainname.com","name":"chandresh","expires":"2013-07-05T11:47:32"}*

***I have tryed to write CryptoJS Code equivalent to above C# working code.***

*Somehow, the encryption/encoding done is not valid encodedData. Please help*

```
var json_data = '{"email":"chandresh@domainname.com","name":"chandresh","expires":"2013-07-05T11:47:32"}';
var site_key = "84129";
var api_key = "0d2c15da-b36f-4a9c-8f44-93eb95811e2e-05e1fb36-54aa-44fc-888e-45d2669c3013";
var _iv = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var options = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: _iv, keySize: 128/8 };

// Create the 16-byte salted hash     
var saltedHash = CryptoJS.SHA1(api_key + site_key);
saltedHash.sigBytes = 16;

saltedHash = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(saltedHash);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(json_data,saltedHash, options);

// the Base64-encoded encrypted data
var encodedData  =  encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
encodedData = encodedData.trimEnd("=");          // Remove trailing equal (=) characters       
encodedData = encodedData.replace(/\+/gi, "-");  // Change any plus (+) characters to dashes (-)
encodedData = encodedData.replace(/\//gi, "_");  // Change any slashes (/) characters to underscores (_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Base64-encoding the key in the JavaScript version. Just pass in the `saltedHash` variable without encoding and it should work.

There are other issues with this cryptographic system though. A static IV is almost always a security issue. Key derivation is also dubious here.

Comment: +1 I agree with both of those crypto issues, and would add since this is most likely a webservice, this design of just plain AES-CBC w/ PKCS7 padding encryption makes a chosen ciphertext attack to recover the plaintext pretty easy.

Comment: @jbtule And that's even only relevant if padding oracles do not apply, in that case the plaintext is really easy to obtain. - basically I have to point my padding oracle attack application to the correct location.

Comment: @ntoskrnl, you are right removed Base64-encoding the key in the JavaScript version.

_i.e. removed this line_

**saltedHash = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(saltedHash);**

_also updated initialization of \_iv as_

**var _iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse([]);**

Thanks for everything